# Increase font size of drop down list in input box HTML

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, inputbox

I want to increase the font size of items that comes in drop down list when I click downward arrow in input box that contains list.

I tried to add font-size in  tag and I could see the font size increased in input box after I select a item from drop down but I want to see the drop down items itself larger.

Input box with set of listitems :

```
<input type="text" list="itemnames">
<datalist id="itemnames">
<option>'txt1'</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Font size option needs to be on select tag, not option tag:

```
<select style="font-size:50px;">
    <option>txt1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `$ins_sql_stm = "SELECT distinct item_name FROM `items_home`";
$ins_sql = mysqli_query($host_connect, $ins_sql_stm);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ins_sql)) {
  $id = $row['item_name'];
  echo '<select style="font-size:500pt;">';
  echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$id.'</option>';
  echo "</select>";
}`    I use mysql to fetch data from a table. After I added select statement then also I coudl n't increase the font size